# How to apply Theme in React-Toolbox 2 when using Create React App

Tags: css, create-react-app, react-toolbox

I've spun up a new project using create-react-app and have been successful in getting react-toolbox 2.0.0-beta.6 to work with default theme. Similarly, I've been able to apply global theme changes by setting "customProperties" in my package.json.

In a separate project, not using CRA (i.e. using post-css modules), I have been able to customize individual components (e.g. PurpleAppBar from the react-toolbox-examples repo).

However, I am struggling to figure out how to do something like the "PurpleAppBar" example when using react-toolbox-themr. When I run `npm run toolbox` style info from the theme is not picked up in the compiled css.

Is there currently a way to style individual components using react-toolbox-themr suitable to use within create-react-app?

Comment: I faced the same issue and after wasting 3 hours on something so simple I installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui ... worked like a charm in 2 min with CRA

Comment: @MimiEAM, I have gone this route as well since my original post. Material UI at Next is far easier to use than the previous version and I am quite happy with it.